# disableing primefaces selectBooleanCheckbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox, primefaces, jsf-2.2, selectbooleancheckbox

I try to disable a primefaces input component directly in Javascript.
It is about a `p:selectBooleanCheckbox` that should be disabled (and enabled) based on some other conditions (if certain value is filled in another `p:inputText`).

My environment looks like:

- JSF Mojarra 2.2.7
- Primefaces 5.1
- PF Extensions 3.0.0
- Apache Tomcat 7.0.47

I've tried already a lot to do so - same things working for normal `p:inputText` are not working for the `p:selectBooleanCheckbox`.

JSF-Part:

```
   <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="thing"
      widgetVar="thingWv"
      disabled="#{myBB.chkboxDisabled}"
      pt:pfId="thingChkBox"
      styleClass="thingy"
      itemLabel="The Thing"
      value="#{myBB.chkbox}" />
```

Javascript part for disabling:

```
   console.log ('disable the thing' );
   $('[pfId*=thingChkBoxLabel]').addClass("ui-state-disabled");
   $('[pfId*=thingChkBox]').addClass("ui-state-disabled");
   $('[pfId*=thingChkBox]').prop('disabled', true);
   $('[pfId*=thingChkBox]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   $('[pfId*=thingChkBox] > div > input').addClass("ui-state-disabled");
   $('[pfId*=thingChkBox] > div > input').prop('disabled', true);
   $('[pfId*=thingChkBox] > div > input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   $('[pfId*=thingChkBox] > div.ui-chkbox-box').addClass("ui-state-disabled");
   $('[pfId*=thingChkBox] > div.ui-chkbox-box').prop('disabled', true);
   $('[pfId*=thingChkBox] > div.ui-chkbox-box').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   PF('thingWv').disable();
```

I've also tried some more js things didn't remember ... but now I don't know how to proceed. (after this it looks like disabled but checking and unchecking is still possible)

Another way would be a  and having in the disabled attribute something like `#{myBB.othervalue > 5}`. But I don't like this as it needs another round trip for this simple action.

Comment: Why don't you use your logic for disabling the button in Bean?

Comment: This defeats the advantage of antispoofing/tampering that PF has. Server side it is still enabled. So by changing it in a browser developer tool, your client-side disabling is bypassed

Comment: I understand the concern about the antispoofing but it is (for this) not a problem. Further more the roundtrip for this special case is too much, so I stick with disabling on client side.